# TopologyException on left join

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to do a simple `stream.leftJoin(table)` but get the following exception at runtime:

```
TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore null is not added yet
```

This is what my code roughly looks like, I commented out the implementation details to keep it short:

```
val streamsConfiguration: Properties = {
  val p = new Properties()
  // api config
  p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG /**/)
  p.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG /**/)
  // kafka broker
  p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  // local state store
  p.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "./streams-state")
  p.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
  // serdes
  p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerde])
  p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerde])
  p
}

val builder = new StreamsBuilderS()

val rawInfoTable: KTableS[String, String] = builder.table("station_info")
val infoTable: KTableS[String, StationInfo] = rawInfoTable.mapValues{jsonString =>
  /** */
}.filter(/** */)
  .mapValues((/** */)

val rawStatusStream: KStreamS[String, String] = builder.stream("station_status")
val statusStream: KStreamS[String, StationStatus] = rawStatusStream.flatMapValues{jsonString =>
  /** */
}

val outputStream: KStreamS[String, String] = statusStream
  .leftJoin(infoTable, calculateStats)
  .filter((_, availability) => {
    /** */
  })
  .map((stationId: String, availability) => {
    /** */
  })

outputStream.to("low_availability")

val streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration)

streams.cleanUp()
streams.start()
```

I even tried to manually add a `StateStore` via:

```
val store = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("my-store")
val storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(store, new StringSerde(), new StringSerde())
val builder = new StreamsBuilderS()
builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder)
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything. I'm using the kafka streams wrapper from lightbend: `"com.lightbend" %% "kafka-streams-scala" % "0.2.1"`

All the examples I checked don't seem to care about adding a state store, so I'm somewhat confused. Can somebody point me in the right direction? Does this have to do something the `STATE_DIR_CONFIG`? Or with the Kafka cluster I'm running locally?

Comment: I would recommend to use Apache Kafka instead of Lightbend: there is a Scala API for Kafka Streams since v2.0 release: https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#scala-dsl -- note: it's not required to upgrade your broker to upgrade Kafka Streams.

Comment: Thanks, I think that worked so far.